# Python Drawing Pie Chart/Bar Graph using while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I'm having difficulty starting a while loop trying to generate a program that will generate a pie chart or bar graph from numbers that a user will input. How does the while loop need to be written so it's not looping forever? I know I could use a for loop for a finite sequence but i'm not too experienced in that. any guidance would be helpful!

from SimpleGraphics import *

print("Chart Menu: 1.Pie Chart, 2.Bar Chart")

chart = int(input("enter either 1 for pie chart or 2 for bar chart:"))

if chart == 1:

```
 title = input("Enter the title of the chart: ")

 numSec = int(input("Enter the number of sectors: "))

 tSum = int(input("Enter the total sum of all sector values:  "))

 gsize = int(input("Ehter the grid size (Between 10 and 400): "))

 yLabel = input("Enter the label for the Y-Axis:")
```

while loop

-the name of each sector

-the value each  sector

-draw pie chart

if chart == 2:

```
title = input("Enter the title of the chart: ")

numCat = int(input("Enter the number of categories: "))

grid = int(input("Ehter the grid size (Between 10 and 400): "))
```

while loop

-name of each category

-value for that category

-draw bar graph

Comment: Please, add an indent to your code to format it properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to give user an option to interrupt `while` loop. Try something like this:

```
while True:
    reply = int(input("Chart Menu: 1.Pie Chart, 2.Bar Chart, 3.Exit"))
    if reply == 3:
        break
    elif reply == 1:
        # do stuff for pie chart
    elif reply == 2:
        # do stuff for bar chart
    else:
        print("Sorry, I don't understand you. Try again, please.")
print("Bye!")
```

Here `while True` is an infinite loop, but `break` statement asks Python to go out of the loop immediately (go to line `print("Bye!")` in this example).

See e.g. [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_while_loop.htm) for more details on `while` loop in Python.